# My scraper does not work on google-compute-engine with 403 forbidden

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, google-compute-engine

I wrote a web scraper with `python3.6` and it's working well on my own server.

When I'm trying to run it(exactly same URL) on my `google-compute-engine`, It fails with `HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`.

## My Code and result on my server

Again, It works well.

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> response = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.kumkangho.co.kr/bk.popup.info.php?date=20190413&pa_uid=1")
>>> print(response.readline())
b'<!-- <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"> -->\r\n'
```

## Result on google-compute-engine

[image]

I think it's not blocked by the server to which url goes but GCE.

Comment: Could you check your firewall settings on GCP once and ensure that port 80 is open on the same

Comment: Could you please give me some details about "on the same"?

Comment: VPC Network > Firewall Rules

Comment: I added rules that accept all port of 0.0.0.0/0 on both.(in-bound/out-bound) but still it does not work.

Comment: This URL by default give a 403 response

Comment: I'll check it out right away.

Comment: It's weird. It's working well on my local python.

Comment: Could you please show me your script?

Comment: I'm afraid that I have to ask you to check it through your brower.

Comment: Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /bk.popup.info.php on this server. I just hit this resource through my browser

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185537/discussion-between-kim-and-supratik-majumdar).

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of test, I found that the opposite server is blocking access from unwanted countries.

I set the `http_proxy` and it's working now.

@Supratik Majumdar thanks for your help.